# I am using Date Time in the List Tile if date ending time is 24hr remaining then it shows countdown timer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, stream

Suppose There is an event which will be started on 15/jul/2023 now when there is 24hr remaining it shows like this 23hr/32min/3sec. My problem is that it is all good on first page but when I send this data to other class and want to show the same date and the countdown timer then the countdown timer is static on the second screen it is not updating by every second like on first screen. Below is the Navigator for sending data

```
     Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: filteredProducts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    final product = filteredProducts[index];
                    final currentState = getProductState(product);
                    String statusText;
                    Color statusColor;

                    if (currentState == ProductState.InProgress) {
                      statusText = 'InProgress';
                      statusColor = Colors.green;
                    } else if (currentState == ProductState.Done) {
                      statusText = 'Done';
                      statusColor = Colors.orange;
                    } else if (currentState == ProductState.StartDate) {
                      final remainingTime = ref.watch(
                          remainingTimeProvider(product.startDate.toDate()));
                      statusText = remainingTime.when(
                        data: (value) => value ?? '',
                        loading: () => 'Loading',
                        error: (error, stackTrace) => 'Error',
                      );

                      statusColor = Colors.blue;
                    } else {
                      final remainingTime = ref.watch(
                          remainingTimeProvider(product.endDate.toDate()));
                      statusText = remainingTime.when(
                        data: (value) => value ?? '',
                        loading: () => 'Loading',
                        error: (error, stackTrace) => 'Error',
                      );
                      statusColor = Colors.red;
                    }

                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ProductDetails(
                                attendeeCount: '21',
                                requiredTickets:
                                    product.requiredTickets.toString(),
                                documentId: product.id,
                                images: product.productInfo.images,
                                statusColor: statusColor,
                                description: product.description,
                                title: product.title,
                                status: statusText),
                          ),
                        );
```

This is my second screen code

```
      Text(
                          status,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: statusColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        )
```

here i am using status for showing date or if 24hr remining then show countdown timer

Below is my reminingTimeProvider for countdown timer

```
 final remainingTimeProvider = StreamProvider.family<String, DateTime>((ref, startDate) {
   return Stream<String>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (int _) {
     final currentDate = DateTime.now();
     final remainingDuration = startDate.difference(currentDate);

     if (remainingDuration.isNegative) {
       return '';
     } else {
       final days = remainingDuration.inDays;
       final hours = remainingDuration.inHours % 24;
       final minutes = remainingDuration.inMinutes % 60;
       final seconds = remainingDuration.inSeconds % 60;

       if (days > 0) {
         final dateFormat = DateFormat('dd.MMM.yy');
         return dateFormat.format(startDate);
       } else if (hours > 0) {
         return '$hours:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
       } else if (minutes > 0) {
         return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
       } else {
         return '${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} sec';
       }
     }
```

Every thing is good on first screen(HomeScreen) but on the second screen(ProductDetail) the countdown timer is static. I just want it dynamic